# How to make JS regex check for minimal number of letters and numbers/signs?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have to write function that would create a regex that would be used to validate password based on the specific requirements.

The detailed specifics of the task can be found here: https://www.codewars.com/kata/6175064bf1c7eb002038df72

I've written the following function that generates following regexes:

1.) If the input array is [["[a-z]", 5], ["[0-9]", 5]] and the minimal length of the password is 10 the regex generated is:

```
/^((?=.*[a-z]){5,})((?=.*[0-9]){5,})[a-z0-9]{10,}$/
```

2.) If the input array is [["[!-A]", 2], ["[Z-a]", 2]] and the minimal length of the password is 5 the regex generated is:

```
/^((?=.*[!-A]){2,})((?=.*[Z-a]){2,})[!-AZ-a]{5,}$/
```

Here's my code:

```
 function generateRegex(charClasses, minLength) {
  let combClasses = `${charClasses[0][0]}${charClasses[1][0]}`.replace(
    '][',
    ''
  );

  let group =
    '^((?=.*' +
    charClasses[0][0] +
    `){${charClasses[0][1]},})` +
    '((?=.*' +
    charClasses[1][0] +
    `){${charClasses[1][1]},})${combClasses}{${minLength},}$`;

  let regex = new RegExp(group);

  return regex;
}
```

and it works in majority of the tests, however the are couple of tests which don't work correctly i.e.:

```
// Numbers and letters
const charClasses = [
  ['[a-z]', 5],
  ['[0-9]', 5],
];
const minLength = 10;
const yourRegex = generateRegex(charClasses, minLength);

// True
console.log('Must be true:', yourRegex.test('abcda12345')); // 5 [a-z] and 5 [0-9]
console.log('Must be true:', yourRegex.test('aaaaa11111')); // 5 [a-z] and 5 [0-9]
console.log('Must be true:', yourRegex.test('a1b2c3d4e5')); // 5 [a-z] and 5 [0-9]
console.log('Must be true:', yourRegex.test('1aaa11a1a1')); // 5 [a-z] and 5 [0-9]

// False
console.log('Must be false:', yourRegex.test('abcd1234'));  // 4 [a-z] and 4 [0-9]
console.log('Must be false:', yourRegex.test('abcd12345')); // 4 [a-z] and 5 [0-9]
console.log('Must be false:', yourRegex.test('a1b2c3d4'));  // 4 [a-z] and 4 [0-9] 
console.log('Must be false:', yourRegex.test('b111111111')); // 1 [a-z] and 9 [0-9] <- shows true, but have to be false



// Signs and letters
const charClasses = [
  ['[!-A]', 2],
  ['[Z-a]', 2],
];
const minLength = 5;
const yourRegex = generateRegex(charClasses, minLength);

// True
console.log('Must be true:', yourRegex.test('!#$Aaa')); // 4 [!-A] and 2 [Z-a]
console.log('Must be true:', yourRegex.test('$!^[]')); // 2 [!-A] and 3 [Z-a]
console.log('Must be true:', yourRegex.test('12345ZZZZZ')); // 5 [!-A] and 5 [Z-a]
console.log('Must be true:', yourRegex.test('!a#$Aa')); // 4 [!-A] and 2 [Z-a]
console.log('Must be true:', yourRegex.test('[$!]^')); // 2 [!-A] and 3 [Z-a]
console.log('Must be true:', yourRegex.test('1Z2Z3Z4Z5Z')); // 5 [!-A] and 5 [Z-a]

// False
console.log('Must be false:', yourRegex.test('!#$Aa')); // 4 [!-A] and 1 [Z-a]  <-- shows true but, have to be false
console.log('Must be false:', yourRegex.test('$!^[')); // 2 [!-A] and 2 [Z-a] but the string length is less than 5
console.log('Must be false:', yourRegex.test('!!!!!')); // 5 [!-A] but 0 [Z-a]
console.log('Must be false:', yourRegex.test('')); // 0 [!-A] and 0 [Z-a]
```

It looks like the check for the minimal amount of particular type of signs ([a-z]){5,} or [0-9]){5,} or [!-A]){2,} or [Z-a]){2,}) in the password doesn't work in those examples.

But I don't understand why, could anybody help me with that? What's wrong with my regex?

Answer (score -1):

The problem with the `^((?=.*[a-z]){5,})` lookahead pattern is that it checks 5 times if there is a lowercase char in the string, each time starting from the beginning. In other words you get a match if you have a single lowercase character.

You need to change the pattern to `^(?=(.*[a-z]){5,})`. With this you look for any number of chars, followed by a lowercase char, repeated 5+ times.

Here is a working example with your test cases:

```js
function generateRegex(patternDefs, minLength) {
  console.log('generateRegex(' + JSON.stringify(patternDefs) + ', ' + minLength + ')');
  return new RegExp(
    '^' +
    patternDefs.map(def => {
      return '(?=(.*' + def[0] + '){' + def[1] + ',})';
    }).join('') +
    '[' +
    patternDefs.map(def => {
      return def[0].replace(/\[(.*)\]/, '$1');
    }).join('') +
    ']{' + minLength + ',}$'
  );
}

let re = generateRegex([ ['[a-z]', 5], ['[0-9]', 5] ], 10);
console.log('==> regex: ' + re.toString());
[
  'abcda12345',
  'aaaaa11111',
  'a1b2c3d4e5',
  '1aaa11a1a1',
  'abcd1234',
  'abcd12345',
  'a1b2c3d4',
  'b111111111'
].forEach(str => {
  console.log(str + ' => ' + re.test(str));
});

re = generateRegex([ ['[!-A]', 2], ['[Z-a]', 2] ], 5);
console.log('==> regex: ' + re.toString());
[
  '!#$Aaa',
  '$!^[]',
  '12345ZZZZZ',
  '!a#$Aa',
  '[$!]^',
  '1Z2Z3Z4Z5Z',
  '!#$Aa',
  '$!^[',
  '!!!!!',
  ''
].forEach(str => {
  console.log(str + ' => ' + re.test(str));
});
```

Result:

```
generateRegex([["[a-z]",5],["[0-9]",5]], 10)
==> regex: /^(?=(.*[a-z]){5,})(?=(.*[0-9]){5,})[a-z0-9]{10,}$/
abcda12345 => true
aaaaa11111 => true
a1b2c3d4e5 => true
1aaa11a1a1 => true
abcd1234 => false
abcd12345 => false
a1b2c3d4 => false
b111111111 => false
generateRegex([["[!-A]",2],["[Z-a]",2]], 5)
==> regex: /^(?=(.*[!-A]){2,})(?=(.*[Z-a]){2,})[!-AZ-a]{5,}$/
!#$Aaa => true
$!^[] => true
12345ZZZZZ => true
!a#$Aa => true
[$!]^ => true
1Z2Z3Z4Z5Z => true
!#$Aa => false
$!^[ => false
!!!!! => false
 => false
```